# Java : Operator Precedence when methods are involved

Tags: java

Kindly assist. I am preparing for the Java 7 Programmer 1 exam and came across this question in one of the enthuware Tests.

### Question :

Consider the following method:

`static int mx(int s)
     {
         for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
         {
           s=s+i;
         }
         return s;
      }`

And the following code snippet:

```
`   int s=5;
    s += s + mx(s) + ++s;
    System.out.println(s);`
```

What will it print ?

End Question

According to the rules on operator precedence , I started by evaluating ++s getting a value of 6 for s, followed by using 6 in the mx method to get a value of 8. Next I added 6+8+6 =20. Then finally carried out the assignment operation as s = 6+ 20 = 26.

The correct answer is 24. I cannot seem to figure out how they come to that answer. Kindly shed some light.

Comment: mx(6)==9 or mx(6)==8 ????

Comment: Sorry about that. You are right  mx(6) == 9. First Iteration (i=0) : 6+ 0 =6 . Second Iteration (i=1) : 6+ 1 =7 . Third Iteration (i=2) : 7+ 2 =9 . Fourth Iteration (i=3) : Condition part is false.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't start with `++s`, since the evaluation is from left to right.

```
s += s + mx(s) + ++s;
```

is the same as

```
s = 5 + 5 + mx (5) + 6;
```

which is

```
s = 5 + 5 + 8 + 6 = 24
```

Comment: Thanks @Eran. So When is operator precedence used  ? I thought we would use it here cause there are multiple operators namely Prefix , addition and assignment. Don't the rules say we start with Prefix, then addition and finally assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `s` does not change on the `++s` because the evaluation of the expression is left to right.

You can check this by modifying your code like this:

```
public static int  mx(int s){
    System.out.println(s);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        s=s+i;
    }
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int s=5;
    s += s+mx(s)+ ++s;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The print statement in `mx(int s)` will print out the value for `s`, revealing that it is still `5`.

---

Additionaly, if `mx(int s)` had been passed the value `6`  it would return `9` instead of `8`.